# Why do I get an empty list while scraping website and end in type error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, typeerror

Hi i am trying to do web scraping in `pyhton` but it returns empty `string`.
I couldn't solve the problem as I am a beginner. As far as I researched, I get a

**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

when I do it, can you help?

When I use this shape it returns empty data

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib import response


kitapurl = "https://1000kitap.com/alintilar"

response = requests.get(kitapurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
gelen_ana_veri = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'text-alt'})
print(gelen_ana_veri)
```

but if i do it this way i get type error

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib import response


kitapurl = "https://1000kitap.com/alintilar"

response = requests.get(kitapurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
gelen_ana_veri= soup.find_all('meta',attrs={'property':'og:description'})['content']
print(gelen_ana_veri)
```

The error i got

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fratk\OneDrive\Belgeler\twbot\1001kitap.py", line 11, in <module>
    elem = soup.find_all('meta',attrs={'property':'og:description'})['content']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `find_all` returns a list, so you can't index it with `['content']`; you need to either iterate through it, or use a numeric index, then use `['content']` on the individual items

Comment: So why does the code I write with the span tag return empty?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're hitting their web-scraper protection? Try writing the `response.content` out and seeing if it matches what you expect...

Answer (score 1):

**Always and first of all check the response to your request or / and your `soup`.**

- is the request successful?
- are the expected elements included?
- is there information that suggests that content is being withheld?
- ...

**The website is protected via cloudflare**

> Attention Required! | Cloudflare Please enable cookies. Sorry, you have been blocked You are unable to access1000kitap.comWhy have I been blocked? This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution...

**So this page does not want to be scraped and you should respect that** - From a technical point of view there is still an option to access the page and its contents e.g. with use of `cloudscraper`.

Anyway, the `ResultSet` of your `find_all()` cannot be treated as a `dict`, a solution would be to iterate or as in the case simply use `find()` as there is only one descriptive meta - Also use `get()` to avoid error if attribute is not available:

```
soup.find('meta',attrs={'property':'og:description'}).get('content')
```

##### Example

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

kitapurl = "https://1000kitap.com/alintilar"
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser={'browser': 'firefox','platform': 'windows','mobile': False})

response = scraper.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")
gelen_ana_veri= soup.find('meta',attrs={'property':'og:description'}).get('content')
print(gelen_ana_veri)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `content` doesn't exist.

If you try `elem = soup.find_all('meta',attrs={'property':'og:description'})` you will get nothing or an empty list `[]`

You would also get the `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` if you were to try `gelen_ana_veri = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'text-alt'})['content']`

first check to see if the element you are looking for exists with soup.find_all() function in a more broad sense. Then if you find your element, then try to drill down more of its classes, or properties.

Here is a basic example of trying to find what you are looking for:

```
gelen_ana_veri = soup.find_all('meta')
print(gelen_ana_veri)
```

This will output a list of every meta tag and then you can see of any specific tags you are looking for.

Comment: Since I viewed the source of the website, I saw that it was concentin, I may have misunderstood because I just started, but my goal is to draw the texts on the site and when I do as you say, it returns empty, in any case, there are both meta tags and span tags with texts on the website, and when I pull spandan it returns empty, how can I do it so that it does not return empty?
  If you want to check it out, the link to the website is:https://1000kitap.com/kesfet

Comment: Your question - `how can I do it so that it does not return empty?` | My Answer - Do what @Jiři said in his comment and iterate or print through the soup find, but in a more broad sense like I mentioned in my answer. I updated the answer to show a basic example of how to look more broadly.

Comment: I tried what you said, but I still couldn't reach the texts, could it be that the site is preventing me from receiving the data?
Is there such an option?

Comment: Write out `response. Content` to see if it matches what you expect?